# shaperead or mapshow not working on matlab

Tags: matlab, mapping, shapefile

I am trying to do something like

```
path = 'c:/the/path/to/my/file.dbf'
map = shaperead(path,'BoundingBox',bBox)
mapshow(map)
```

After a while (probably reading the map), the program exits correctly, but no map is shown.

using a path to a smaller, less dense map works properly.

using the same path without a bounding box limit just hangs.

How can I debug this?

Thanks

Comment: but this depends on what shape file you are using, i.e. what is `path`

Comment: Probably `path` is a variable with the actual path to the file, so you have to pass it to the function as a variable (remove the quotes ' ').

Comment: @GameOfThrows and BlackAdder: path is the path to a .dbf file, which is in a folder that has everything a shapefile needs.
BlackAdder , i passed the path correctly, i thought that was clear. question editted.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make my comments clear, I think the reason `BoundingBox` works is because it limits the number of features you import. In other word, I think your import is hanging because there are too much data to import, but this depends on the shape file.

Comment: @gameofthrows when I limit the bounding box to be small (50,50) or (100,100) nothing happens. the program just finishes with no error and no map is showed.

Comment: I think that is because none of your features intersect with the bounding box, the bounding box will only import features that it intersects with.

Comment: is the shapefile sorted, or does it always go over the entire file even for small bounding boxes?

Comment: @GameOfThrows you were correct. I needed to change the bounding box to intersect. the problem was the initial placement could not be deduced without loading the entire map first and seeing the coordinates. I had to load everything which took several hours and 8GB of ram.
is there a way to know valid coordinates without loading the entire map?

Comment: @Gulzar Matlab will require you to load in all the coordinates, you can however try to edit the file and see if you can reduce the number of coordinates (either in Matlab after loading or outside using other tools) - in industry, maps are usually create with different LoDs (level of detail) a low level one that can be loaded fast for a general idea and a high level one for detailed analysis, when you generate the shape files you should keep this in mind.